# Visual Studio Code: Changing language syntax highlighting within a document with multiple languages

Tags: language, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I have files with snippets in multiple different languages. I would like to change the syntax highlighting for a different blocks of code with, for example, comment blocks. Example would be:

```
SQL Procedure:

#sh sql
```

```sql
-- Establish procedure:
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS -- ...
-- Basically, SQL syntax highlighting here until #endsh.
```

```
#endsh

Required PHP code for processing and verifying:

#sh php
```

```php
<?php
// Some PHP code ...
?>
```

```
#endsh
```

I've split the code blocks for markdown syntax hightlighting. I've used #sh as an example from the built-in #region and #endregion that are in vscode, just as an example to get the point across.

I have looked for this for a while and couldn't find an answer, or an extension that would allow this. Basically, is this possible currently with some method, or is it possible with an extension that might not exist yet? If no such extension exists, where would be a good place to start to create this myself?

Thanks a lot.